# Installation of MongoDB via SoftwareCenter failed

Tags: permissions, mongodb

I installed mongodb from the Ubuntu Software center, but when I want to run it from command line I get an error message like:

```
mongod --help for help and startup options
Sun Feb 12 10:51:14 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2613 port=27017                  dbpath=/data/db/ 64-bit 
Sun Feb 12 10:51:14 [initandlisten] db version v1.8.2, pdfile version 4.5
Sun Feb 12 10:51:14 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
Sun Feb 12 10:51:14 [initandlisten] build sys info: Linux allspice 2.6.24-28-server #1 SMP Wed Aug 18 21:17:51 UTC 2010 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_46_1
Sun Feb 12 10:51:14 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen std::exception: Unable to create / open lock file for lockfilepath: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied, terminating
Sun Feb 12 10:51:14 dbexit: 
Sun Feb 12 10:51:14 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Sun Feb 12 10:51:14 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Sun Feb 12 10:51:14 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Sun Feb 12 10:51:14 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Sun Feb 12 10:51:14 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Sun Feb 12 10:51:14 closeAllFiles() finished
Sun Feb 12 10:51:14 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Sun Feb 12 10:51:14 [initandlisten] couldn't remove fs lock errno:9 Bad file descriptor
Sun Feb 12 10:51:14 dbexit: really exiting now
```

I tried to create a repertory /data/db from my root but for some reason it's not working.
Does anyone have a pointer?

Answer (score 2):

What kind of file system are using on `/data/..` ? I imagine it could be a problem if you are using **NTFS** on that mount point.

Another problem could be the version of BOOST you have installed. I am not sure if MongoDB will work with BOOST 1.46. In the [build description for Windows](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Boost+and+Windows) at least, they state:

> We have successfully compiled version **1.42** – you might want to try that version or higher, but not 1.45 or later. 1.45 changed the interface to the boost::filesystem library and we've yet to catch up. See additional notes section at end of this page too.